# C# Different result using HashAlgorithmProvider and SHA.ComputeHash

Tags: c#, cryptography, sha512

I'm trying to compare two SHA512 checksum, one come from an UWP app and the other come from an standard Windows exe.

UWP code :

```
        string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(file.Path);

        IBuffer buffUtf8Msg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(fileContent, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        HashAlgorithmProvider objAlgProv = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Sha512);
        IBuffer buffHash = objAlgProv.HashData(buffUtf8Msg);

        String strHashBase64 = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(buffHash);

        return strHashBase64;
```

Windows exe code :

```
    using (SHA512 SHA = SHA512Managed.Create())
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
            return Convert.ToBase64String(SHA.ComputeHash(fileBytes));               
        }
    }
```

When i'm compare the two results, they are differents.

If someone have an explanation, it's would be very helpful.

Comment: Maybe I don't have enough coffee yet, but in the second example you don't appear to be actually reading the file, you've only just opened it and created a buffer.

Comment: Also, in your first example, `File.ReadAllText` is "text-aware" meaning it will attempt to detect the encoding using various methods, so if you've got a BOM in the file that would be used for reading but ultimately not be part of the hash. In the second example, if you read the file raw and don't use an encoding to interpret things, the BOM _would_ be part of the hash.

Comment: It might even detect a different encoding for the file than UTF-8, so the hash may not be over the bytes within the file - with or without BOM.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers ! It was an encoding issue. I have add encoding to UTF8 in my windows exe and that works.